# UITableView Mix of Static and Dynamic sections Cells ? throw error -[__NSSingleObjectArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'

Tags: swift, uitableview

I am trying to create a UI table view that mixes Dynamic and Static cell section "something like WIFI settings views in ops".

The first section will be static. It will hold the text field and labels. The second section will be dynamic it will show the members of the group.

I get this exception:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSSingleObjectArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond
>   bounds [0 .. 0]'

```
class CreateGroupTableViewController: UITableViewController {
// ----------
// MARK: - Constants
// ----------

private struct Section{
    static let Static = 0
    static let Dynamic =  1
}

private struct CellId{
    static let Dynamic = "DynamicCell"
}

// ----------
// MARK: - variables
// ----------
 var users = [User]()

// ----------
// MARK: - Lifecycle
// ----------

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    users = LibraryAPI.shared.getUsers()
}

// ----------
// MARK: - UITableViewDataSource
// ----------

 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    return false
}

// ----------

 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    return false
}

// ----------

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if section == Section.Static {
        // count of your data source items
        return 3
    }
    else 
   if section ==  Section.Dynamic {

    let usercount = users.count
       print(String(users.count))
       return usercount
   }
    else {
        return super.tableView(tableView, numberOfRowsInSection: section)
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell.EditingStyle {
    return .none
}

// ----------

  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    print("test")
    if indexPath.section == Section.Dynamic
    {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "membersCell")

        if cell == nil {
            // create dynamic cell from xib or with default style
            cell = UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "membersCell")
        }

        // customize your dynamic cell
        if let cell = cell
        {
             cell.textLabel?.text =  users[indexPath.row].username  // "srfsdf" 
            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = users[indexPath.row].email  //"users[0].email"

            return cell
        }
    }
    let cell = super.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAt: indexPath as IndexPath)
    return cell

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]` suggests something is trying to read `users` before it has been populated, so it's still in the initial empty state:

```
var users = [User]()
```

The only time you try to index `users` is when configuring a cell in your "Dynamic" section, which suggests you've misinformed the tableview about how much data you've got. Also, I don't see any code to report `2` as the number of sections.

Observation: Deferring to `super` for any `UITableViewDelegate` methods seems odd. How would it be in a better position than your own code to know what cell to provide or how many rows are in a section?

Also, consider using the `tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: String, for: IndexPath)` variant as it always returns a cell.